# What type of assembler is this?

Tags: assembly

```
pa ds 1
mvi c,4
mvi d,3
mvi a,0
p1: add c
dcr d
jnz p1
sta pa
end
```

This is the assembly code I'm using, and I am compiling it with a 8085A Emulator. But I can't find out more information to learn. I looked up for MIPS assemler, and found some tutorials, but none work with this compiler.

For example, I tried this:

```
.data
var1:       .byte       4
var2:       .byte       3
var3:       .byte       0

.text

main:
```

But it says they're all unknown commands. Where can I find more information and guides about the type of assembler in the first example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google `mvi dcr sta`.

Comment: @simonzack Can you be more specific please? All I found was pre-made codes, which I don't understand.

Comment: Read the results carefully. It's clearly in the top 10 results.

Comment: @simonzack Do you mean this http://www.das.ufsc.br/~werner/eel7030/8085/instrucoes8085Detalhadas.pdf ?

Comment: _"I am compiling it with a 8085A Emulator"_ That seems like a pretty strong hint at the code being 8085 assembly. But more importantly, the course you're taking should specify what the target architecture is and contain / point to necessary information like instruction set references etc. If it doesn't, talk to your professor or teaching assistant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using an 8080 type assembler. .data and .text aren't supported by most 8080 type assemblers since they produce a single segment image like a .COM file. Use DB instead of .byte or DW instead of .word . The 8085 has a few extra instruction that can be defined via macros. The Z80 includes a different set of extra instructions, so these 8085 specific instructions were mostly used for the BIOS or utilities specifically meant for an 8085 computer (usually CP/M).

```
ARHL    MACRO           ;ARITH RIGHT SHIFT HL
        DB      10H
        ENDM
DSUB    MACRO           ;HL=HL-BC
        DB      08H
        ENDM
JNXC    MACRO   X       ;JMP IF NOT X CARRY (INX, DCX)
        DB      0DDH
        DW      X
        ENDM
JXC     MACRO   X       ;JMP IF X CARRY
        DB      0FDH
        DW      X
        ENDM
LDHI    MACRO   I       ;DE=HL+I
        DB      28H
        DB      I
        ENDM
LDSI    MACRO   I       ;DE=SP+I
        DB      38H
        DB      I
        ENDM
LHLX    MACRO           ;HL=(DE)
        DB      0EDH
        ENDM
RDEL    MACRO           ;ROTATE DE,CY LEFT
        DB      18H
        ENDM
RIM     MACRO           ;RESET INT MASK
        DB      20H
        ENDM
RSTV    MACRO           ;RST IF V SET TO 40H
        DB      0C8H
        ENDM
SHLX    MACRO           ;(DE)=HL
        DB      0D9H
        ENDM
SIM     MACRO           ;SET INT MASK
        DB      30H
        ENDM
```